# Google Drive get not working

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I've been using the Google Drive PHP files v 1.1.5 files and wanted to upgrade to the PHP v 2.1.2 files.  Been struggling and finding my way around some issues, but stuck on this LAST issue.

The following code worked using the v1 interface, which allowed retrieving the file contents using the google fileID. This fails ($content length = 0) in the v2 interface (exact same code)

```
    // this returns the contents of the file -- download the content....
    $content = $service->files->get($fileID, array('alt' => 'media'));
```

Tried a few way around this, but after spending a few hours, looking for some help. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Nice photo 

Comment: Since the V2 API is not longer supported [google notice](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/php).

You should try directly to go with V3 Instead.
It is not clear when wil they stop accepting V2 request, but could happen any time this yaer.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is the php library that no longer supports v2. There is currently no timescale for the v2 API to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Yea - I'm actually using the v3 interface but the PHP v2.1.2 libraries, using the new interface libraries for PHP some things have changed there and I've been struggling to make ends meet and work again, this issue seems to be the last...???...  time will tell...  anyway success, the code needed to have an additional line added to pull the contents of the file.  See below and at the following link

```
 https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

// this returns the contents of the file -- download the content....
$response= $service->files->get($fileID, array('alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

And now it works correctly....